# Python not iterating through items in a list

Tags: python

I’m trying to make a program that gives a password and then tests the strength of a password. However, this program does not work as expected. The initial generating of the password worked fine before I added the strength testing feature, and other than the strength testing feature, still does. The `check(passw)` function also works fine when on its own, it’s just when I put it in the `for item in passwords_list`  loop, it prints:

```
Currently testing: 

Length under 3 characters.
Could not find a number.
Could not find a symbol.
No uppercase characters were found.
No lowercase characters were found.
```

The code is as follows:

```
import random
import string
adjectives = ['Hairy', 'Skinny', 'Red', 'Flawless']
nouns = ['Rock', 'Table', 'Banana', 'House']
passwords_list = ['']
password = ''

def check(passw):
    safe_unsafe = ['']
    errors_list = ['']
    errors = ''
    if len(passw) < 3:
        errors_list.append('length_under')
        errors = errors + '\nLength under 3 characters.'
    if len(passw) > 16:
        errors_list.append('length_above')
        errors = errors + '\nLength above 16 characters.'
    if not re.search('[0-9]', passw):
        errors_list.append('numbers')
        errors = errors + '\nCould not find a number.'
    for char in passw:
        if char in string.punctuation:
            safe_unsafe.append('y')
        else:
            safe_unsafe.append('n')
    if 'y' in safe_unsafe:
        pass
    else:
        errors_list.append('symbol')
        errors = errors + '\nCould not find a symbol..'
    safe_unsafe.clear()
    for char in passw:
        if char in string.ascii_uppercase:
            safe_unsafe.append('y')
        else:
            safe_unsafe.append('n')
    if 'y' in safe_unsafe:
        pass
    else:
        errors_list.append('upper')
        errors = errors + '\nNo uppercase characters were found.'
    safe_unsafe.clear()
    for char in passw:
        if char in string.ascii_lowercase:
            safe_unsafe.append('y')
        else:
            safe_unsafe.append('n')
    if 'y' in safe_unsafe:
        pass
    else:
        errors_list.append('lower')
        errors = errors + '\nNo lowercase characters were found.'
    safe_unsafe.clear()
    if errors:
        print(errors)
    else:
        print('Your password is all clear!')

    other_t = input('Would you like to test another password? y/n ')
    if other_t == 'y':
        password = str(input('What is your password? '))
        check(password)
    else:
        exit()

num_of_pass = input('How many passwords would you like?')
numbers = input('Would you like numbers? y/n').lower()
symbols = input('Would you like symbols? y/n').lower()
for num in range(int(num_of_pass)):
    password = password + random.choice(adjectives) + random.choice(nouns)
    if numbers == 'y':
        password = password + str(random.randint(1, 100))
    if symbols == 'y':
        password = password + str(random.choice(string.punctuation))
    passwords_list.append(password)
    print(password)
# test the password
for item in passwords_list:
    print('Currently testing ' + item)
    check(item)
```

Comment: Please show the full input and output of the session. E. g. how many passwords have you requested?

Answer (score 2):

After some reverse engineering and testing of your code, I think I have came to a conclusion.

On line seven, you assigned `password_list` to a list with an empty string. Because of this, the first password that you checked, is actually an empty string.

To fix this, make `password_list = ['']` to `password_list = []`. After making this fix, I was able to make your code run.

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating an epty list. So when you check the first item on list it checks an empty string, which don't pass the test.

Then you end your check function calling it again, before going to the next item in the for loop.

You have to start with an epty list so simply change `passwords_list = ['']` to  `passwords_list = []`

And remove the test another password from inside the check function to keep the for loop running.

Answer (score 0):

**First** you are creating a list with empty string

```
password_list = [''] #is wrong

password_list = [] # is correct
```

**Second** Your code is not welsuited for working on a list of items. You need to remove the last 6 lines of your code to make it work perfectly.

```
other_t = input('Would you like to test another password? y/n ')
if other_t == 'y':
    password = str(input('What is your password? '))
    check(password)
else:
    exit()
```

These lines should be removed